# How to incorporate a while loop within a Python try/except?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, exception, while-loop, try-catch

Selenium Webdriver with Python regularly fails to launch the Firefox browser, and a retry is often needed. Usually a single or second retry is sufficient, so I do the following:

```
try: 
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
except WebDriverException, e:
    print "Unable to load profile, retrying"
    try: 
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    except WebDriverException, e:
        print "Unable to load profile, retrying"
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

This is no longer serving me, as it is now regularly taking 3 or more retries before the browser launches. What is the neatest way to incorporate a `while` loop such that it keeps retrying until the browser successfully loads (at which point `self.driver` will exist as an object)?

Note: I know that there is a slight chance that an infinite loop may be encountered, but for the purposes of supplying suggestions, you may disregard this fact.

Comment: well, why not `while self.driver is None` ?

Answer (score 3):

How about defining `self.driver` as `None` before the `while` loop and then looping till its not `None` ? Example -

```
self.driver = None
while not self.driver:
    try: 
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    except WebDriverException, e:
        print "Unable to load profile, retrying"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use python's `else` clause. Check [python's exception handling](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions)

```
while True:
    try:
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    except WebDriverException, e:
        print "Unable to load profile, retrying"
    else:
        break
```

Comment: This is correct way to bad this idiom in Python is a bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

It is very interesting for you to say loading Firefox will often fail, it has never happened to me before. I have been running Selenium tests for a while now. You may want to investigate why your Firefox driver keeps failing, does it need an update?

I suggest you do implement a limit on how many time it will retry.

```
numberOfRetry = 5
while (driver==None):
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    except:
        numberOfRetry-=1
        if numberOfRetry <= 0:
            logging.critical("Maximum number of retry reached")
            break
```